# jqplot strange behaviour of chart

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jqplot

I using jqplot to plot chart and display it inside twitter bootstrap modal window. In modal window I have 5 tabs and when I am displaying jqplot chart in tab 5 strange data is being plotted while the same thing is plotted correctly when I display it in tab 4. I am using following code to display jqplot chart

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cosPoints = [];
for (var i=0; i<2*Math.PI; i+=0.1){
 cosPoints.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
}
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [cosPoints], { 
  series:[{showMarker:false}],
  axes:{
    xaxis:{
      label:'Angle (radians)'
    },
    yaxis:{
      label:'Cosine'
    }
  }
});
$('a[href=\"#yw1_tab_5\"]').on('shown', function(h) {
            plot1.replot();
            }
        );
});
```

Following are the images of plot
[image: correct plot]
[image: wrong plot]

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening even though I am using same code to display?

Comment: Did you try plot1.replot(true, true)? Or try to copy code for creating plot into "on shown" event handler.

Comment: yes I tried replot(true, true). But anyway how this will make difference since with same code one one tab it is displayed correctly while on other tab it is showing some extra data point plot.

Comment: I don't know, but you could always create new chart with same data and apply it on "dash5" as temporary solution.

Comment: Strange, I created a new graph but in that also some numbers are appearing on graph for each point while these number don't appear if I display it on other tabs.

Comment: Try something like this: delete everything except chart on "dash5" and try, delete all content from other tabs and try, or both. Look into firebug that you might have javascript error on the page.

Comment: Just before dash5 in dash4 tab I am displaying jqplot bar graph using barrenderer plugin and due to this these extra points are being displayed on graph. If I remove that bar graph from dash4 the graph is displayed correctly on dash5. Now I don't know why is this happening? Does options enabled for  jqplot bar graph are also automatically enabled for graph on dash5 also?

Comment: I suppose you use different variable  names  for these two charts? Am I right?

Comment: yes I am using different variable names.

Comment: Ok I found out where the problem was it was due to this line of code `$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;` which I was using in plotting bar graph on dash4. Now I don't why is this happening? Also if I enable something in one javascript code then they remain enable in other javascript code also unless I exclusively disable them?

Comment: Paste your complete code at http://pastebin.com/ to see more detailed.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/mrXCEnHU)

Comment: You don't need slashes ("\") in plot6="...", starts at line 61 (style:\"x\") to the 75...

Comment: I need these slashes since I am using this javascript code inside  php code so " will not be recognized unless I use \".